# $_SESSION Variable not carrying to other page

Tags: php, session

This is my first page. The $_SESSION variable is working correctly. When doing a var dump it has the info i need.

```
<?php
// Start a session.  This is necessary to hold on to  a few keys the callback script will also need
session_start();

// Include the TumblrOAuth library
require_once('tumblroauth/tumblroauth.php');

// Define the needed keys
$consumer_key = "";
$consumer_secret = "";

// The callback URL is the script that gets called after the user authenticates with tumblr
$callback_url = "http://tumblrstats.sytes.net/info/chooseBlog.php";

// Let's begin.  First we need a Request Token.  The request token is required to send the user
// to Tumblr's login page.

// Create a new instance of the TumblrOAuth library.  For this step, all we need to give the library is our
// Consumer Key and Consumer Secret
$tum_oauth = new TumblrOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);

// Ask Tumblr for a Request Token.  Specify the Callback URL here too (although this should be optional)
$request_token = $tum_oauth->getRequestToken($callback_url);

// Store the request token and Request Token Secret as out chooseBlog.php script will need this
$_SESSION['request_token'] = $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['request_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

// Check the HTTP Code.  It should be a 200 (OK), if it's anything else then something didn't work.
switch ($tum_oauth->http_code) {
  case 200:
    // Ask Tumblr to give us a special address to their login page
    $url = $tum_oauth->getAuthorizeURL($token);

    // Redirect the user to the login URL given to us by Tumblr
    header('Location: ' . $url);


    break;
default:
    // Give an error message
    echo 'Could not connect to Tumblr. Refresh the page or try again later.';
}
exit();
?>
```

This second page is where it breaks. var dump on the $_SESSION variable gives nothing, so i get an undefined index error when trying to access it.

```
<?php
//Load library
session_start();
require_once('auth/tumblroauth/tumblroauth.php');
require_once('../tumblr/lib/Tumblr/API/Client.php');
include('functions.php');
include('blogClass.php');

// Define the needed keys
$consumerKey = "";
$consumerSecret = "";

// Create instance of TumblrOAuth. Give consumer key and secret.
$tumblrOAuth = new TumblrOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $_SESSION['request_token'], $_SESSION['request_token_secret']);

//Retrieve an Access Token.
$accessToken = $tumblrOAuth->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

// Remove Request Token and Secret
unset($_SESSION['request_token']);
unset($_SESSION['request_token_secret']);

// Make sure nothing went wrong.
if (200 == $tumblrOAuth->http_code)
{
  //Everything is good
}
else
{
    die('Unable to authenticate');
}

//Present our variable more cleanly
$token       = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
$tokenSecret = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];

//Create a new instance of our client
$tumblrClient = new \Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
$tumblrClient->setToken($token, $tokenSecret);

//Convert stdObject to Array
$userInfo = objectToArray($tumblrClient->getUserInfo());

//User Data
$userName = $userInfo['user']['name'];
$userLikeNum = $userInfo['user']['likes'];
$userFollowingNum = $userInfo['user']['following'];
$userDefPostFormat = $userInfo['user']['default_post_format'];

//General Individual Blog List
$blogNameList = array();
$blogNameID = array();
$blogID = 0;
foreach ($tumblrClient->getUserInfo()->user->blogs as $blog)
{
    $blogNameString = $blog->name;
    //Without ID
    $blogNameList[] = $blogNameString;
    //WithID
    $blogNameID[] = $blogNameString;
    $blogNameID[$blogNameString] = $blogID;
    //Add 1 to Blog ID
    $blogID++;
}
?>

<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Your Tumblr Stats</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="chooseBlog">
    <?php
        foreach($blogNameList as $value)
        {
            $imgUrl = objectToArray($tumblrClient->getBlogAvatar($value, 128));
            echo "<div id='$value' class='blogSelector'><img src=$imgUrl><div id='innerContainer' class='blogInfo'><a href='http://www.$value.tumblr.com' id='info'>$value.tumblr.com</a></div></div>";
        }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: This is the error thrown.

Notice: Undefined index: request_token in /home/www/tumblr/htdocs/info/chooseBlog.php on line 14 Notice: Undefined index: request_token_secret in /home/www/tumblr/htdocs/info/chooseBlog.php on line 14

Comment: Does your two pages are on the same domain? Sounds like your session cookie doesn't get sent to the second page.

Comment: They are on the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the pages between the first page (your first file) and the last file (second one) must have `session_start()` else you will lose the PHP session.

Are the first page accessing the second one?

Comment: The first page redirects to Tumblr Verification, which then uses the callback url to redirect to the second page. I've had this working before but after some changes it's broken and I'm not sure what I did.